# Applying a selectors style to an element as a pulse animation

Tags: jquery, css, kendo-ui

Kendo UI has a textbox:focus style defined for every available theme:

```
.k-textbox:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 7px 0 #357ebd;
}
```

I would like to apply this style to a textbox as an animation ( fade-in/fade-out) when a field is updated out-of-band, and whether or not the field has the current focus.

I'm guessing I'd have to kick this off using javascript and jquery when an update is received for a particular field.

[Example](https://dojo.telerik.com/EqEcAhow/5)

Comment: Try adding a transition to `.k-textbox`, e.g. `.k-textbox { transition: box-shadow 0.1s linear; }`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the trigger has to happen via JavaScript. The transition will do the effect, as pointed out by daGUY.

Here is an example for using jQuery:

```
$(".your-textbox-selector").on( "change", function() {

    $(this).css("box-shadow", "0 0 7px 0 #357ebd").css("transition", "box-shadow 0.1s linear");

})
```

Comment: how can I use the ".k-textbox:focus" style from the active style sheet. KendoUI has many color themes define in different CSS files, and my particular app lets the user switch themes so I can't use a hard coded value for the box-shadow color.  I updated my question with a link to an example.